# Why the url mapping is unable and shows 404 on google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
class BookMe(Handler):
    def render_book(self, deal=""):
        deals = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Book ORDER BY created DESC")
        self.render("book.html", deal=deal,deals = deals)

    def get(self):
        render_book()

    def post(self):
        deal = self.request.get("deal")
        if deal:
            b = Book(deal = deal)
            b.put()
            self.redirect("/")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                           ('/unit2/rot13', Rot13),
                           ('/book', BookMe),
                           ('/unit2/signup', Unit2Signup),
                           ('/unit2/welcome', Welcome),
                           ('/blog/?', BlogFront),
                            ],debug=True)
```

i indicate the 'book' is mapping to BookMe handler, but when i type the /book 
it raise a 404 and said /book did not match any patterns in application configuration.

can any any give me a tip?

and here is my app.yaml

```
application: byrdnee
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: blog.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

my main file's name is blog.py

Comment: Just to double check, you are prefacing `/book` with the host? `http://localhost:8080/book`, for example? If so, can you also post your `app.yaml`?

Comment: Make sure you configured your app.yaml correctly https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig

Comment: In app.yaml change url: /* to url: /.*

Comment: @Gricha  i changed, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: And just to confirm, you are using the full URL?

Comment: Ok I'll give it another shot. Change it to url: .*

Comment: that Handler class your class extends is a subclass of webapp2.RequestHandler?

Comment: @RenanIvo I think the error would be 500 if it was not.

Comment: Third time's a charm - can you confirm that you are entering the full URL? :) Also, does it work for any of your other handlers? If so, I would suggest reducing your code to just the `/book` handler and the `Handler` class itself (as well as any other inheriting classes). Basically get it to the fewest lines of code that still present the problem and then paste the full contents of `blog.py`. It is possible there is something going on in your code that is causing the odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have your full code but something like the following should work

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class BookMe(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        deals = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Book ORDER BY created DESC")
        template_values = {
            'deals': deals,
        }

    self.response.write(template.render("book.html", template_values))
```